# Why does building a Rust/GTK3 app with yocto fail?

Tags: rust, yocto, gtk3

I have a working Rust/GTK3 app. When trying to compile it with yocto I'm getting the following errors:

> warning: Could not run `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gobject-2.0" "gobject-2.0 >= 2.48"`   error: failed to run custom build command for
> `gobject-sys v0.15.10`

How can I fix it? Perhaps somebody has an example that uses Rust/GTK3 and successfully builds with the yocto?

The problem is only with the Rust app. I am able to build a C++/GTK3 app with yocto.

Answer (score 0):

If I run that command on my setup, then I get the following output:

```
$ "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gobject-2.0" "gobject-2.0 >= 2.48"
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib64/libffi/include -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

So, you either do not have pkg-config or you don't have gobject or you have an unsuitable version of gobject.

Comment: My output is exactly the same. The point is that I am able to build and run that application successfully outside of yocto, but when yocto is trying to build it it fails with that, which is surprising because I have all those packages there.

Comment: are you able to build rust app that uses gtk3 with yocto?

Comment: @RomekLomek I have not tried that.

Comment: then we are talking about different environments, which is kinda pointless...